# A language switcher in Symfony 2.4

Tags: php, symfony, locale, language-switching

I have an object Language, and I can add, delete and update languages from the admin page.

What I want to do, is to add a language switcher, I put this html/twig code:

```
 {% for language in languages %}         
      <li><a href="{{ path('evr_footer_switch_language',{'locale': language.code | lower }) }}">{{ language.language | capitalize }} ({{ language.code }})</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
```

And an action `the route for the action is evr_footer_switch_language`, the one I used in the switcher above:

```
 public function switchlanguageAction($locale = 'en') {

        $this->get('session')->set('_locale', $locale);
        $request = $this->getRequest();
       $request->setLocale($locale);
        return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
    }
```

This is the route I defined for the action/controller switchlanguageAction()

```
evr_footer_switch_language:
    pattern: /language/switch/{locale}
    defaults: { _controller: EvrHomeBundle:Footer:switchlanguage, locale: en }
```

It seems to me very simple in principle, you click on the link of the language (got from the database), send the code of the language (exemple : 'fr', 'en', 'zh' etc...) to the action as a $locale variable, then set the Locale of the session/request to this value.

The problem is that none of this works, and the language is still 'EN' (default value).

**Note** According to the requirements of this project, The language can't be mentioned in the URL (like fr/articles, en/articles), **but the same URL (/articles/) can show in different languages, this is why I didn't use the pre-defined slug (_locale)**.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in search for some more details in order to write an answer I stumbled upon this `Symfony` cookbook entry: **[Making the Locale "Sticky" during a User's Session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html)**

I think that's exactly what you need ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer +1, but ...I created a listener, and Added it to the services.yml (the same steps described in the article you mentioned), then I set the locale from the controller, but in vain...it didn't work yet.

Comment: Thank you so much again , I applied what the doc says, But to set the locale I used only `$request->setLocale()`, and now I added the `$this->get('session')->set('_locale')`, it works ... Best answer !

Answer (score 3):

Symfony 2.6: 
I used the LocaleListener mentioned in "Making the Locale Sticky", but also had to use this to get things working properly:

```
/** from Controller
 *
 * @Route("/changeLanguage/{changeToLocale}", name="changeLanguage")
 *
 */
public function changeLanguageAction($changeToLocale){
    $this->get('request')->attributes->set('_locale', null);
    $this->get('session')->set('_locale', $changeToLocale);

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
        return;
    }

    // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
    if ($locale = $request->query->get('swich_language')) {

        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        $routing = $this->router->match($request->getPathInfo());

        $route_params = array();

        foreach ($routing as $key => $value) {
            if($key[0] !== "_")
            {
                $route_params[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $parameters = \array_merge($route_params, array("_locale" => $locale));
        $url = $this->urlGenerator->generate($routing['_route'], $parameters);

        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

You can add as a kernel request and with querystring swich_language you can change it

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer +1 , in fact the question is 4 years old, but it is still useful to have many solutions, thank you. <3